# Fixed trouble with optionals, but now my labels and images are not being set to what I tell them to be set to

Tags: swift, xcode

I fixed a force-unwrapping optional trouble that I had by using guard statement, but now my Label and ImageViews are not changing to what I tell them to be changed to. What exactly is the issue and how do I fix this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var startImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var destImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!

var selectedStartCount: Int?
var selectedDestCount: Int?
var enteredFuel: String?
var fuelDouble: Double?
var startPoints = [String]()
var destPoints = [String]()
var results = [String]()
var trip: String?
var start: String?
var dest: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    startPoints = ["Sydney", "Canberra", "Melbourne", "Adelaide", "Perth", "Darwin", "Brisbane"]
    destPoints = ["Sydney", "Canberra", "Melbourne", "Adelaide", "Perth", "Darwin", "Brisbane"]
    destPoints.remove(at: selectedStartCount!)

    start = startPoints[selectedStartCount!]
    dest = destPoints[selectedDestCount!]
    guard var fDouble = fuelDouble else {return}
    fDouble = Double(enteredFuel!)!

    if start == "Sydney"
    {
        if dest == "Canberra"
        {
            trip = "The distance between \(start!) and \(dest!) is 294km. Based on your car fuel consumption, you will need \(294*fDouble/100)L of fuel that cost around $\((294*fDouble/100)*1.40)."
        }
    }

    startImage.image = UIImage(named: startPoints[selectedStartCount!])
    destImage.image = UIImage(named: destPoints[selectedDestCount!])
    resultsLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    resultsLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    resultsLabel.text = trip
}
```

Label and ImageViews are properly connected. The first three optionals are coming from segue prepare pass. The last five lines are supposed to be setting label to `trip` string and two ImageViews to image assets which are named with whatever is chosen in the arrays, and yes, the image assets are named the same.

What I get in the view is two blank spaces instead of images and "Label" inside the label instead of the string expected.

Comment: When you have a "force-unwrapping optional trouble" you shouldn't just "fix" it with a guard statement. You should find out _why_ that thing is nil, when it shouldn't be. It appears that `fuelDouble` is nil. Aren't you supposed to do `fuelDouble = Double(enteredFuel)` at some point?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of `viewDidLoad` and step through the code, making sure you get past the guard statement.

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah, apparently the guard statement did nothing

Comment: Did adding `fuelDouble = Double(enteredFuel)` before the guard fix it though?

Comment: @Sweeper Oh, yes! It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `viewDidLoad` is returning from this guard:

```
guard var fDouble = fuelDouble else {return}
```

Which means that `fDouble` is nil. Based on your description, `fDouble` is not one of the variables that get passed a value from the previous VC. And you are not setting it anywhere, so obviously it is nil.

Judging from the context, you probably meant to parse `enteredFuel`:

```
// put this before the guard
fDouble = Double(enteredFuel!)
```